# Adding a multicast route to an interface in OSX

Tags: macos, routes, multicast

I have a VM running in Fusion that I want to hit by routing a specific endpoint address through the virtual ethernet interface (multicast DNS, in particular). First I was sending packets and inspecting with Wireshark noticing that nothing was getting through. Then I thought to check the routing table

```
$ netstat -rn | grep vmnet8
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
172.16.12/24       link#29            UC              2        0  vmnet8      !
172.16.12.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0       35  vmnet8      !
```

But unlike other interfaces,

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
224.0.0.251        a1:10:5e:50:0:fb   UHmLWI          0      732     en0
224.0.0.251        a1:10:5e:50:0:fb   UHmLWI          0        0     en8
```

There was no multicast route. So I added it:

```
$ sudo route add -host 224.0.0.251 -interface vmnet8
add host 224.0.0.251: gateway vmnet8
```

And so it was true

```
$ netstat -rn | grep vmnet8
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
172.16.12/24       link#29            UC              2        0  vmnet8      !
172.16.12.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0       35  vmnet8      !
224.0.0.251        a1:10:5e:50:0:fb   UHmLS           0       13  vmnet8
```

I was also sure to check the interface flags to ensure it had been configured to support multicast

```
$ ifconfig vmnet8
vmnet8: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        ether 00:70:61:c0:11:08
        inet 172.16.12.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 172.16.12.255
```

Still, no multicast packets I send are getting through. I noted that the other interface's multicast route have different flags than the default ones given to my added route. Namely `UHmLWI` vs `UHmLS`. The differences I can see are insignificant. From `man netstat`:

```
 I       RTF_IFSCOPE      Route is associated with an interface scope
 S       RTF_STATIC       Manually added
 W       RTF_WASCLONED    Route was generated as a result of cloning
```

Then again, I'm not claiming to be a routing expert. Perhaps a multicast route entry must be made somehow differently?

You'll note that the `Use` column is non-zero, despite no packets showing in a sniffer.